How to make LazyVerticalGrid last odd item in the horizontally center with the same size of other items in Jetpack Compose?
Assalamu alaykum.
I have LazyVerticalGrid with 2 fixed columns. ItemList count given to this may be odd or even.
Problem is that, when there are odd number of items, last item couldn't being in the center with same size of other items.

I just want to post my solution that take my whole day. I couldn't find any solution in the internet until I came up to this.
My Solution:
Column(
     Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
  ) {
     if (itemElements.isNotEmpty()) {
                    var minSize by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(IntSize(600, 600)) // Default size
                    }
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .weight(1f),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(36.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                            itemSeparatorPadding, Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                        ),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(itemSeparatorPadding),
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
                    ) {
                        items(itemElements.size, span = { index ->
                            val spanCount = if (itemElements.size % 2 != 0 && index == itemElements.size - 1) 2 else 1
                            GridItemSpan(spanCount)
                        }) { index ->
                            val isItemLastOdd = (itemElements.size % 2 != 0 && index == itemElements.size - 1)
                            Box(
                                contentAlignment = if (isItemLastOdd) Alignment.Center else Alignment.CenterStart
                            ) {
                                TextOption(
                                    modifier = if (isItemLastOdd) Modifier.size(minSize.toDpSize()) else Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                                            if (it.size.height < minSize.height) {
                                                minSize = it.size
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
     }  
  }


// Item
@Composable
fun TextOption(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
       // Item UI
    }
}

Now the last odd item in the last row of LazyVerticalGrid in centre of row with same size of other items.
If you have more optimal solutions, I will really appreciate it.
Thank you!

Here I change the last item's position with offset modifier. Offset value is calculated in onGloballyPositioned taking into account itemSeparatorPadding.
Column(
    Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    val lastOddItemIndex = remember(itemElements) {
        if (itemElements.size % 2 == 1) {
            itemElements.lastIndex
        } else {
            -1
        }
    }
    var lastItemOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(36.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            itemSeparatorPadding,
            Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(itemSeparatorPadding),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(itemElements) { index, item ->
            val modifier = if (index == lastOddItemIndex) {
                val density = LocalDensity.current
                Modifier
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        val itemWidth = with(density) { it.size.width.toDp() }
                        lastItemOffset = (itemWidth + itemSeparatorPadding) / 2
                    }
                    .offset(lastItemOffset)
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
            TextOption(modifier = modifier)
        }
    }
}

